# MonoMac missing xib.designer.cs files

Tags: c#, macos, mono, monodevelop, monomac

Ok, So I am learning MonoMac. The first thing is that all of the tutorials have a MainWindow.xib.designer.cs file, I have only the MainWindow.xib file. When I do work on the interface builder, I get no auto-generated code. I am using monodevelop v2.8. No matter what I do, when I create a new MonoMac project, the xib files never have the accompanying *.xib.designer.cs files.

Any ideas before I throw this out the window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MD 2.8 there are no longer *.xib.designer.cs files, because in Xcode 4 xibs can no longer define classes. Instead, MD 2.8 works by syncing registered C# classes to/from Objective-C stubs. These classes will have *.designer.cs partial class files to reflect changes made in Xcode.

Comment: I actually suspected it was something like that. However, my designer file remains unchanged after editing the xib file. What am I doing wrong? I am following this tutorial.  http://mjhutchinson.com/journal/2010/06/09/monomac_in_monodevelop

Comment: The *.xib.designer.cs was never generated directly from your UI, it was generated from any custom classes you'd defined in the Class Inspector in Interface Builder. Now that's no longer possible and the custom classes must be defined directly in code. With MonoMac/MonoTouch Xcode integration, you can do this in C# or in Objective-C. Xcode will automatically modify custom classes when you drag-connect into the source file. See http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/tutorials/transitioning_from_xcode_3_to_xcode_4 - it's MonoTouch, but applies to MonoMac.

Comment: Ok, so it sounds like, since I am going to have to hand write this stuff, I need to just learn the NS framework. I usually hand write my Windows.Forms code anyhow, I just need to learn the paradigm. Is there a good tutorial/ explanation of how the library works?

Comment: was that your blog I linked to?

Comment: Note that you don't *have* to hand write your UI code or outlet/action - in most cases you'll just need the classes created by the MonoDevelop templates, the you can drag-connect the outlets/actions in the Xcode designer.

Comment: You'll have to learn about the concepts of the AppKit classes regardless whether you construct the UI in code or from the designer. Unfortunately there isn't much in the way of tutorials for using AppKit from C#, however, since MonoMac is essentially a wrapper that allows you to use the AppKit Objective-C classes (and many others), all of the Objective-C docs, tutorials and books that document how to work with AppKit map over fairly directly. Many samples from Apple and from Objective-C books have been ported over to MonoMac and you can find them on GitHub: https://github.com/mono/monomac

Comment: You might find the video on my blog of the presentation I gave at NDC11 useful. It's a mixture of a high-level view of MonoMac and some rather heavy details on the workings of Objective-C and the bridge. Although knowing/understanding anything about Objective-C and the bridge isn't actually necessary to use MonoMac, it can be useful when reading Obj-C docs and samples.

Comment: I've posted a couple of getting started guides on my blog that may help you get started with this - http://tufnelltech.blogspot.com/